# calculate normal vector in differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry

I am reading differential geometry from do carmo book.here he gave the formula to calculate normal vector as $$N(q)=\frac{Xu \wedge Xv}{|Xu \wedge Xv|}$$.

But I am not sure how to calculate for Cartesian.

As example for plane $$ax+by+cz+d=0$$ or sphere $$x^2+y^2+z^2=1$$ or cylinder how should I calculate normal vector using the formula.

Can someone elaborate the procedure please.

Comment: $X_v$ and $X_u$ in the formula mean two linearly independent tangent vectos to the surfaces at the point $q$, write these vector down using coordinates, and compute the wedge product. 

What could probably be useful and more immediate in the cases you present above is that the surfaces are described as level surfaces of functions from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}$. In this case, one knows that the gradient of the function is normal to the surface. This provide another way to compute a normal vector.

Comment: Thanks for ur help.but can u pleased tell me how can I write those equations w.r.t the vectors u and v.

Comment: It gets a bit complicated very quickly to write them down explicitly, moreover you have to choose them, so you have a lot of freedom. For example, consider the north pole of the sphere. Here the tangent vectors can be $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$. Applying the formula above you get that the normal vector is $(0,0,1)$. For the plane, find three points $P,Q,R$ lying on the plane. then $P-Q$ and $R-Q$ will be tangent vectors to the plane (why?). Apply the formula, you will get that the normal vector at any point is $(a,b,c)$.

Comment: usually a more std symbolics used is $\frac{X_u\times X_v}{||X_u\times X_v||}$, 'cuz the symbol $\wedge$ is for exterior product.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little unsure about your notation, but typically you start with a parametrization $\mathbf{x}(u, v): \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$.

For example, a plane can be parametrized as $\mathbf{x}(u, v) = u\mathbf{a} + v\mathbf{b} + \mathbf{c}$ where $\mathbf{a, b}$ are vectors parallel to the plane and $\mathbf{c}$ is a point that lies inside the plane.

Likewise, you can find a parametrization for a sphere [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametrization%20of%20a%20sphere).

Once you have a parametrization, then you compute $\displaystyle \frac{ \partial \mathbf{x} }{ \partial u}$ and $\displaystyle \frac{ \partial \mathbf{x} }{ \partial v}$, which are what $X_u$ and $X_v$ are here.  Finally, your normal vector will be given by $\displaystyle \frac{ \partial \mathbf{x} }{ \partial u} \times \frac{ \partial \mathbf{x} }{ \partial v}$.

As per convention, we finish up by normalizing it, so you'll want to divide by $\displaystyle \left\lvert \frac{ \partial \mathbf{x} }{ \partial u} \times \frac{ \partial \mathbf{x} }{ \partial v} \right\rvert$.

Answer (score 1):

The formula you cited from Do Carmo's book applies in the case where you have parametric equations $(u,v) \mapsto \mathbf{x}(u,v)$ that give a surface point $\mathbf{x}(u,v)$ corresponding to any given parameter values $(u,v)$.

If the surface is given in "implicit" form $f(x,y,z)=0$, then there's a different formula for calculating surface normal:
$$
\mathbf{N} = \operatorname{grad} f = \nabla f =\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}, 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \right)
$$
If you want a unit vector, divide this vector by its length, of course.

So, you have two choices: (1) invent some parametric equations for your surface, and use your formula, or (2) use the formula I gave above. For your plane and sphere examples, the second approach is easier, I think. If you prefer to use the first approach, then @Kaj showed you how.

More info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)).